# Reload/Refresh SuperView of the ViewController with transition animation ios4.0+

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am new to ios development.

### Setup

The view hierarchy is as follows:

MyViewController has the following

**myView** ( UIView)

-> **Navigation Bar**

-> **UiCollectionView**

-> **UIButton**

### What is going on ??

RootViewContoller presents myViewController

*(things work  till this point)*

### What i want to do after that??

On clicking "UIButton" :- reload the "**myView**" with a different text in the **navigation bar** and different content in the "**UICollectionView**".

Animation requirements : Reload/Refresh of the view should happen with transition effects of the view for eg: flip from left, curl up etc.

->I tried [myView setNeedsDisplay] to see if the view reloads without animation - *doesn't work*

```
    -(IBAction) onReload {
         [self.myView setNeedsDisplay];
    }
```

-> I also tried

```
    [UIView transitionWithView:myView ....
```

although i don't know what to put in animation block which would trigger the refresh of view.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second instance of your view controller, properly setup as far as its title and `UICollectionView` content are concerned, then when handling your button action, do:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:NO];
```

This is the basic way you handle a navigation hierarchy under iOS: you create new controllers and push/pop them to/from the navigation controller.

If you are not using a navigation controller, rather you are trying to implement the same functionality as a navigation controller would handle on your own, I strongly suggest you to use a [navigation controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead... :-)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. using a navigation controller makes sense in my case . I will try doing that. IT will simply a lot of things. But out of curiosity , what if i don't want use a navigation controller, what can be done?? I understand apple's quest to make bad designing difficult. But , lets say i did not have a navigation controller and i did not want to use it..